# How do I change a div's width and width with JQuery in Greasemonkey

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

I'm trying to change some css properties with jquery inside greasemonkey. If I goto the site and edit the values manually with firebat everything works but for some reason this grease monkey script wont work and I can't figure out why.

I'm  trying to set the width of `div#feedlyFrame div#feedlyPart0 div#feedlyPage div#mainArea div#timeline` width to 100% and change the line-height of `#feedlyTabsHolder` to 20px and the height of `div.icon` to 20px.

Here it is:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        fix feedly
// @namespace   reader
// @include     http://www.feedly.com/*
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ready(function() {
   $("div#feedlyFrame").width("100%");
   $("div#feedlyPart0").width("100%");
   $("div#feedlyPage").width("100%");
   $("div#mainArea").width("100%");
   $("div#timeline").width("100%");
   $("#feedlyTabsHolder").css("line-height", "20px")
   $("div.icon").height("20px");
 });
```

Comment: **How** does this not work?  What are the error messages? Does the target page even use jQuery? **Link to the target page.**

Answer (score 2):

Selector should be a string:

```
$("div#feedlyFrame").width("100%");
```

Answer (score 0):

**-EDIT-**

See if you can isolate `width()` as the problem.

Try `$("div#feedlyFrame").css({'border', 'solid 1px red'});` or something similar. If there is no result, the issue may be with how you're trying to access the element, or if you *can*.

Any shot that this element is a `live` element?

---

OP,

Have you tried `.css()` in place of `.width()` ?

```
$("div#feedlyFrame").css({'width', '100%'});
```

Comment: No luck with changing the border so I must be trying to access the element wrong. I'm not sure what a live element is, I'm not much of a jquery programmer I just know a couple basic things. Here is an image of me properly changing the width with firebug https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3774984/Untitled.jpg